# Sub select where clause criteria

Tags: t-sql

Working on my first ETL assignment for a class and need assistance with the insert query for the transformation, specifically getting the authorID to be inserted into the Transform table. .  My incoming data is:  [Incoming data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZf8o.png)

My transform table has 3 columns, `Book(varchar(50)`, `ISBN(varchar(50)`, `author(int)`. 
The correct author value needs to come from the author table which has:
`id(int)`, `FirstName(varchar(35)`, `LastName(varchar(35)`.

What do I need for the where clause on the sub select?

```
INSERT INTO TRANSFORM.NewBook
    SELECT 
        nb.book,
        ISBN,
       (SELECT a.id 
           FROM Library.Author AS a
           WHERE nb.Author = ????????? AS Authorid
       FROM [EXTRACT].NewBook AS nb)
```

Comment: What columns are on NewBook?

Comment: Sorry, Extract.NewBook has Book(varchar(50), ISBN(varchar(50), WholesaleCost(varchar(50) and  author(varchar(50).

Comment: It seems nb.Author = CONCAT_WS(' ', a.FirstName, a.LastName)... there's no much more in Incoming Data.

Comment: 00Riser, I received incorrect syntax near ','-

 INSERT INTO TRANSFORM.NewBook
 SELECT 
 nb.book,
 ISBN,
 (SELECT a.id FROM Library.Author AS a
   WHERE nb.Author = (' ', a.FirstName, a.LastName) as AuthorId
 FROM [EXTRACT].NewBook AS nb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a join to get the data you are after, which looks to be on the author's name, so I'd try:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSFORM.NewBook
        SELECT nb.book ,
               nb.ISBN ,
               a.id
        FROM   extract.newbook bn
               JOIN library.author a 
                   ON CONCAT_WS(' ' , a.firstname, a.lastName) = nb.author;
```

concat_ws is for sqlserver 2017. You can try `CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastName)` or the old standby of `a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastName = nb.author`

Comment: Is there something that needs to be done to enable the Concat_WS function?  Getting the below error message:

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'CONCAT_WS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @ChrisM ah, its a newer function, so it may not be on your server. You can try `on  a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastName = nb.author`

Comment: @ChrisM do you have authors with no FirstName or Lastname?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu that is a very good question. To get around that (depending on your version of SQL) we could wrap the whole thing in a `trim()` or `ltrim(rtrim())`

Comment: @LordBaconPants  you use `coalesce`  ->  `coalesce (firstname + ' ' + lastname,isnull(lastname,firstname))`

Comment: I was able to use on a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastName = nb.author.  thanks everyone for your help.